# Real-Time Audio Data to Byte-Array

Tags: c#, arrays, audio

With the codes below, the byte array is created as soon as the audio record wav file is saved.

But I need to create this **byte-array real-time, for live streams.**

How can I do this?

```
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder retstrign, int Returnlength, IntPtr callback);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio alias recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.startbutton_Click);

        }

        private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //    throw new NotImplementedException();
            mciSendString("record recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            button2.Click += new EventHandler(this.stopbutton_Click);

        }

        private void stopbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Users\seymk\source\repos\AudioFromSoundCard\test.wav";
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            mciSendString(@"save recsound C:\Users\seymk\source\repos\AudioFromSoundCard\test.wav", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciSendString("close recsound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            //ReadWav(filename, out float[] L, out float[] R);

            using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(filename))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(8, reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample, "");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.Length];
                int read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                short[] sampleBuffer = new short[read / 2];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, sampleBuffer, 0, read);

                string text = "Some metadata........" + Environment.NewLine +
 String.Join(" ", buffer.Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))); // <- encoding 

                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\seymk\source\repos\AudioFromSoundCard\Foo.txt", text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have to use winmm.dll? If it can't produce a live stream of data it seems like the wrong choice for this problem.

Comment: To stream data you would typically split the data into smaller buffers, so that each buffer contain say 10ms of audio. Smaller buffers would typically result in less latency, but also more overhead.

Comment: Use a real audio lib like BASS.NET you'll have complete control.